# Automatic/Scheduled Daily USQL Script Execution

Tags: azure, u-sql

I have several Azure **`USQL`** scripts that I want to run through a daily job at a fixed time. What options I have?

I want to execute each .usql script every day. How can we automate it?

Thank you

Comment: you could always run them via data factory pipeline that has a USQL activity and add a scheduled trigger to the data factory pipeline that is acceptable to your needs

Comment: This is way to broad...

Answer (score 1):

Lot of people were suggesting the use of the Data Factory.
But, the following seems to be working fine for me.Not sure, if there is any issue with that.
1. Created and placed all the USQL scripts in a local folder.
2. Created a PowerShell script to execute these USQL scripts using the Azure Powershell addin.
3. Scheduled the job using the Windows Task Manager to execute this powershell script on a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

but, sometimes we need to automate the execution of pipelines, for this purpose we use the trigger to schedule a specific time on which our pipeline must be execute, you are correct when we need to execute a no. of pipeline but sometime we had a lot of pipelines that execute simultaneously one after another, so we use trigger and also it can be run through .json, python, .net and on the power-shell.

Comment: Thank you. Here, I just need to run the USQL scripts. So, the solution I mentioned below seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the scheduling trigger as
[given link, according to your specific time options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger)